# How can we prove that slopes increase in a convex function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ from the definition?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The definition I have of a convex function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is that for every $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and every $\lambda \in [0, 1]$, 
$$
f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda )y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1- \lambda )f(y).$$

By proving that slopes increase I mean that for $x \leq y \leq z$, we get $$\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} \leq  \frac{f(z) - f(x)}{z-x} \leq \frac{f(z) - f(y)}{z-y}. $$

Is there a simple proof of this which doesn't assume that such a convex function has a non-negative second derivative? It's difficult to see how the definition gets us here.

Comment: It's not true that a convex function needs to be differentiable, let alone twice differentiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**.

Note that if $x\leqslant y\leqslant z$, then we can write 
$$
y=\lambda x+(1-\lambda)z
$$
for some $\lambda\in[0,1]$. *Explicitly*, you can find what is $\lambda$ in terms of $x,y$ and $z$. On the other hand, the definition of convexity tells you
$$
f(y)\leqslant \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(z).
$$
Now do some algebra to get what you want.

Comment: I just wrote the same answer but yours is better

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of this geometrically. The definition of convexity implies $(y,f(y))$ lies on or below the line $L$ through $(x,f(x))$ and $(z,f(z)).$ Suppose it's below. Then the line through through $(x,f(x))$ and $(y,f(y))$ plainly has slope less than the slope of $L.$ And then to move back up to $(z,f(z)),$ the line through $(y,f(y))$ and $(z,f(z)$ plainly has slope greater than the slope of $L.$ Now interpret all of this with appropriate mind-numbing formulae and algebra.

Comment: Sure, it's easy to see that it must be true since convex functions are like parabolas, but unfortunately it's the mind-numbing formulae I need for a proof.